# Are there any good reasons to use ER Diagrams instead of UML Class Diagrams for data modeling? Is ERD the COBOL of data modeling?

Tags: database-design, uml, modeling

Are there any good reasons to use ER Diagrams instead of UML Class Diagrams for data modeling, given the fact that class diagrams subsume ER diagrams? Or is it just for historical reasons because database people are used to ER modeling and are not familiar with UML? So, is ERD the COBOL of data modeling?

UML and ERD are two languages that can do the same thing: model entity (or object) types and their relationship types (or associatons).

Comment: ER diagrams describe the data. UML class diagrams describe classes. Those are two separate tools which solve two separate problems. They are not interchangeable. Also, UML is much more complicated, which may explain why it failed to gain traction among DBAs (and many developers as well, by the way).

Comment: There are no such two different worlds, the world of "data" and the world of "classes". Rather, there is just one world of information management, which has to integrate (the tables of) databases with (the OO classes of) software applications. Please can you provide a good reason why you are using ER instead of UML? Finding it too complicated, when every CS student has to learn it today, may be a reason, but certainly not a good one.

Comment: Why did you write your question in English instead of French, Italian, Spanish, German, Klingon, or Elvish? There are [papers](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~iray/research/papers/csi07.pdf) and [web pages](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html) that talk about different modeling notations. It's the same thing - you use what your audience understands or expects. We speak English on Programmers, so you wrote your question in English. As long as you can express your ideas to others, does it matter what notation(s) you use?

Comment: @Thomas Owens: In the case of data modeling it matters since you normally have to use UML anyway for designing/documenting (at least the model classes of) your apps. And why should we use (and have to learn) two different languages for the same thing?

Comment: For different audiences. Is it easier or clearer for your to express your ideas to the database administrators using ER and the software design to the development team using UML? If so, then maybe use both for the sake of clarity. If an ER diagram provides sufficient detail and clarity, maybe it should be part of your software design and you don't need a UML model for that system. A notation is just a language. Use whatever language and terminology is best for communicating to the target audience - that could be one notation, two, or more.

Comment: I'm going to expand my comments into a full answer now.

Comment: You're asking about data modeling. However, other development methodologies strive to do *domain modeling*, which is for some developers a modeling that is closer to the problem than "just" the data. There is a related question and answers on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704142/why-cant-i-model-my-domain-using-erd

Answer (score 6):

When I am working on a new feature, I *always* use ERDs. To me, the data structures are more important than the classes that will be used to interact with them, and it is important to remember that the two are not necessarily identical. At some point in the future, it may become important for me to split a class into multiple classes, or to combine the object representation of multiple tables into a single class. I may also write programs that rely on the same database using a different language, like Clojure or Haskell, where representing the result of a query as an object is unnatural.

To my mind, *UML* is the "COBOL of data modeling," because it represents a period of object orientation triumphalism, where it was assumed that a single object model was at the same tier as the database. It isn't—and shouldn't be. This, along with Rails-influenced use of software-level data integrity constraints, has led to a lot of pain, in my experience.

Some relevant quotes:

> “Show me your flowcharts and conceal your tables, and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won’t usually need your flowcharts; they’ll be obvious.” – Fred Brooks
>
> “I will, in fact, claim that the difference between a bad programmer and a good one is whether he considers his code or his data structures more important.” – Linus Torvalds
>
> “Rule 5. Data dominates. If you've chosen the right data structures and organized things well, the algorithms will almost always be self-evident. Data structures, not algorithms, are central to programming.” – Rob Pike
>
> “Fold knowledge into data so program logic can be stupid and robust.” – esr

Comment: When you say "data structures [in fact, you rather mean tables] are more important than the classes that will be used to interact with them", then you don't see the point that both the table and the corresponding OOP class are two different implementations of the same UML class, which defines the data structure.

Comment: Of course, not "UML is the COBOL of data modeling", but rather RDB+ERD are the COBOL(d)s of data management!

Comment: Tables are data structures. There are also code-level data structures (arrays, trees, hashes, and so on). All of these are used across paradigms (procedural, functional, and OO languages). "UML Classes" tie code (methods) to data (member variables) in a way that applies *only* to object-oriented languages--and, even then, only in a particularly straitjacketed way.

Comment: It should be clear that when you use UML class diagrams for information/data modeling, you don't define methods. So, what's your point?

Comment: Well, what's yours? If you're using UML class diagrams without including methods, public/private annotations, and so on, you're making an ERD, almost identical to an ERD in crow's foot notation. The only difference is putting attributes inside the entities. "ERD" is a description of the intent of a diagram, not a formal specification.

Comment: Right, this is my point: (the data modeling fragment of) UML class diagrams and ERDs are equivalent, so why make an ERD (instead of an equivalen CD) in analysis, when later you have to turn it into a CD for your design? This is an unnessary double effort.

Comment: I never voluntarily create a UML class diagram, as it has no explanatory power for me and its audience is unclear. Programmers will understand the code; non-technical stakeholders will understand neither code nor a UML class diagram. As such, a simpler format (ERDs) is quick, informal, and allows me to express the vital characteristics of the data without the overhead of UML. Furthermore, as noted, UML is relevant only for object-oriented languages; when writing scripts or using functional languages, it is not useful.

Comment: @gwag Methodologies with domain modeling (à la Craig Larman or DDD) try to use the UML to describe a *problem domain*. In initial iterations of agile modeling, your model is likely inaccurate (spending more time up front to get it perfect is waterfall thinking). Doing domain models in UML help everyone understand the conceptual classes, attributes and associations of the *problem*, to which code is written. Later in your iterations, the domain model stabilizes (and is more complex). You can just keep the design model (or code) as the main model (avoiding duplicate effort).

Answer (score 4):

Different modeling languages (Entity-Relation, Unified Modeling Language, and others) are simply notations for communicating a design to stakeholders. Communicating a design is technical communication, and one of the principles of good technical communication is to communicate the information clearly and concisely. Choosing a modeling notation that is understood by your audience and can communicate the desired information clearly is the first step to achieve this principle.

In his article [A Comparison of Data Modeling Techniques](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/compare.htm), David Hay identifies a number of modeling notations and provides the same example model as expressed in each notation, including [ER diagrams](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/chen.htm), [Information Engineering](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/infoeng.htm), [Barker's notation](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/barker.htm), [IDEF1X](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/idef1x.htm), [Object Role Modeling](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/orm.htm), and [UML](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/uml.htm). Hay discusses the difference between analysts (who need clear and easy to read diagrams that can be reasoned about) and designers (who need complete, rigorous, and expressive diagrams to use for implementation).

Scott Ambler also has some [principles of Agile Modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/principles.htm) are relevant to this:

> - Travel Light. Every artifact that you create, and then decide to keep, will need to be maintained over time. If you decide to keep
>     seven models, then whenever a change occurs (a new/updated
>     requirement, a new approach is taken by your team, a new technology is
>     adopted, ...) you will need to consider the impact of that change on
>     all seven models and then act accordingly. If you decide to keep only
>     three models then you clearly have less work to perform to support the
>     same change, making you more agile because you are traveling lighter.
>     Similarly, the more complex/detailed your models are, the more likely
>     it is that any given change will be harder to accomplish (the
>     individual model is "heavier" and is therefore more of a burden to
>     maintain). Every time you decide to keep a model you trade-off agility
>     for the convenience of having that information available to your team
>     in an abstract manner (hence potentially enhancing communication
>     within your team as well as with project stakeholders). Never
>     underestimate the seriousness of this trade-off. Someone trekking
>     across the desert will benefit from a map, a hat, good boots, and a
>     canteen of water they likely won't make it if they burden themselves
>     with hundreds of gallons of water, a pack full of every piece of
>     survival gear imaginable, and a collection of books about the desert.
>     Similarly, a development team that decides to develop and maintain a
>     detailed requirements document, a detailed collection of analysis
>     models, a detailed collection of architectural models, and a detailed
>     collection of design models will quickly discover they are spending
>     the majority of their time updating documents instead of writing
>     source code.
> - Multiple Models. You potentially need to use multiple models to develop software because each model describes a single aspect of your
>     software. “What models are potentially required to build modern-day
>     business applications?” Considering the complexity of modern day
>     software, you need to have a wide range of techniques in your
>     intellectual modeling toolkit to be effective (see [Modeling Artifacts
>     for AM](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/modelingTechniques.htm) for a start at a list and [Agile Models Distilled](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/index.htm) for
>     detailed descriptions). An important point is that you don't need to
>     develop all of these models for any given system, but that depending
>     on the exact nature of the software you are developing you will
>     require at least a subset of the models. Different systems, different
>     subsets. Just like every fixit job at home doesn't require you to use
>     every tool available to you in your toolbox, over time the variety of
>     jobs you perform will require you to use each tool at some point. Just
>     like you use some tools more than others, you will use some types of
>     models more than others. For more details regarding the wide range of
>     modeling artifacts available to you, far more than those of the UML as
>     I show in the essay [Be Realistic About the UML](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/realisticUML.htm).
> - Content Is More Important Than Representation. Any given model could have several ways to represent it. For example, a UI specification
>     could be created using Post-It notes on a large sheet of paper (an
>     essential or low-fidelity prototype), as a sketch on paper or a
>     whiteboard, as a "traditional" prototype built using a prototyping
>     tool or programming language, or as a formal document including both a
>     visual representation as well as a textual description of the UI. An
>     interesting implication is that a model does not need to be a
>     document. Even a complex set of diagrams created using a CASE tool may
>     not become part of a document, instead they are used as inputs into
>     other artifacts, very likely source code, but never formalized as
>     official documentation. The point is that you take advantage of the
>     benefits of modeling without incurring the costs of creating and
>     maintaining documentation.

He also has some [practices for Agile Modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/practices.htm) to help achieve these principles:

> - Apply The Right Artifact(s). Each artifact has its own specific applications. For example, a UML activity diagram is useful for
>     describing a business process, whereas the static structure of your
>     database is better represented by a physical data or persistence
>     model. Very often a diagram is a better choice than source code -- If
>     a picture is worth a thousand words then a model is often worth 1024
>     lines of code when applied in the right circumstances (a term borrowed
>     from [Karl Wieger's Software Requirements](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735679665)) because you can often
>     explore design alternatives more effectively by drawing a couple
>     diagrams on whiteboards with your peers than you can by sitting down
>     and developing code samples. The implication is that you need to know
>     the strengths and weaknesses of each type of artifact so you know when
>     and when not to use them. Note that this can be very difficult because
>     you have Multiple Models available to you, in fact the [Agile Models
>     Distilled](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/index.htm) page lists over 35 types of models and it is by no means
>     definitive.
> - Iterate To Another Artifact. When you are working on a development
>     artifact -- such as a use case, CRC card, sequence diagram, or even
>     source code -- and find that you are stuck then you should consider
>     working on another artifact for the time being. Each artifact has its
>     strengths and weaknesses, each artifact is good for a certain type of
>     job. Whenever you find you are having difficulties working on one
>     artifact, perhaps you are working on a use case and find that you are
>     struggling to describe the business logic, then that's a sign that you
>     should iterate to another artifact. For example, if you are working on
>     an essential use case then you may want to consider changing focus to
>     start working on an essential UI prototype, a CRC model, a business
>     rule, a system use case, or a change case. By iterating to another
>     artifact you immediately become "unstuck" because you are making
>     progress working on that other artifact. Furthermore, by changing your
>     point of view you often discover that you address whatever it was that
>     causing you to be stuck in the first place. See the essay [Iterate to
>     Another Artifact](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/iterateToAnotherArtifact.htm) for more thoughts.
> - Single Source Information. Information should be stored in one place and one place only. In other words, not only should you apply the
>     right artifact you should also model a concept once and once only,
>     storing the information in the best place possible. When you are
>     modeling you should always be asking the questions "Do I need to
>     retain this information permanently?", "If so, where is the best place
>     to store this information?" and "Is this information already captured
>     elsewhere that I could simply reference?". Sometimes the best place to
>     store information is in an agile document, often it's in source code.
>     [Read here for more details](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/singleSourceInformation.htm).

First need to identify who you are communicating with and what information they need. You should choose the appropriate modeling notation and models to communicate that information to them. Once the models are created, you should use them. They should be reviewed for consistency, they should be transformed into other models, they should be included in documents, or they should be used to guide an implementation.

If you need to, consider investing in training. If you're working with Systems Engineers who use SysML, maybe consider training everyone to read SysML models. If the software team finds the UML notation easier, consider training everyone in UML. It doesn't have to be a formal training class - it could be passing around links to useful websites, buying a few copies of a book for a company library, lunch and learn sessions, or external training (either off-site or a trainer brought in for a session). This may make it easier to reduce the need to have multiple modeling notations used.

Second, don't be afraid to throw away models. Perhaps the first iteration of a model could be an ER diagram. That could be used to understand the data and to create your database. However, in order to add more detail, you may choose to evolve that into a different model type, such as a class diagram. Depending on stakeholder needs, you may need to maintain both models. If you don't, though, throw the first model away so you don't need to maintain it or risk someone finding it and working off of an incorrect model. Future updates to the database could be driven through changes to the class diagram. At the end of the day, though, you don't want the same information captured in multiple places.

---

To very clearly answer your question: yes, there are reasons to use an ER diagram over a UML model. That reason is that the ER diagram is more useful to your stakeholders than a UML model. However, using an ER diagram once doesn't mean that you will keep it for the life of a project or product or that you won't be creating another model in parallel or from your ER model.

I'd also recommend checking out [Scott Ambler's Agile Data](http://www.agiledata.org/) site for more articles and information. It is connected to the Agile Modeling site and is part of the complete [Disciplined Agile Delivery](https://www.pmi.org/disciplined-agile) process, but it does have some good ideas regardless of the methodology you are following.

Comment: Okay, sure, if I have to address an audience that is only familiar with ERDs, but not with UML CDs, then I need to make ERDs. But otherwise, if I don't have to consider such an audience, there seems to be no good reason for using ERDs in analysis/domain modeling, and then later use UML CDs in design modeling. Also Ambler has been suggesting using (suitable profiles of) UML CDs for data modeling in http://agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far seems to have picked up on the difference between conceptual and physical data modelling.

A UML conceptual model will show inheritance relationships, cardinallity and all that good stuff, with the minimum of implementation detail.

The physical model (ER diagram) will differ:

1. Inheritance is no longer obvious. There are three classical ways of mapping inheritance to a relational database - table per concrete class, table per class hierarchy and table per base class plus table per concrete class (holding extra fields only). Many databases have a mix of the three methods, so the ER diagram clearly shows the physical mappings.
2. Many-to-many mappings in the conceptual model translate to a join table in the ER diagram. In the conceptual model this is just a pair of crows feet symbols at the end of the relationship link. In the database it is a real table.
3. Naming conventions are often different. For instance, my organisation would map the Java **Date creationDateTime** field to an Oracle column  **CREATION_TS TIMESTAMP**.

But given the choice, I always go for the ER diagram. You can't easily write SQL given just the conceptual model. Given an unfamiliar and undocumented database, I usually use a reverse-engineering tool to create an ER diagram. With a good tool and a database that has referential integrity constraints defined, you get great results.

The target audience for conceptual models is likely to be enterprise architects and the more technical business analysts.

So in my view, UML and ER diagrams serve similar but quite distinct purposes.

Comment: You are making some good points, but I don't see any reason why not using (suitable forms of) UML class diagrams for making "physical models" or relational data models, using, e.g., a <<fk>>-stereotyped dependcy arrow for expressing a foreign key dependency.